# Do we need internet connection while creating react app with create-react-app project_name

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Do we need internet connection while creating react app with create-react-app project_name?
and why it taking 10-15 min to create app with this command(create-recat-app).

Answer (score 2):

Of course you need internet connection. `create-react-app` is a process to install required `packages` on your system. for more information look at the process here:
[Getting Started](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)